# JavaScript Injection using Man in the Middle Attack

Tags: web-application, attacks

Suppose I am connected to a wifi-hotspot hosted by a malicious attacker. Further, suppose that I am accessing a login page of an fictitious email site `tmail.com` over insecure HTTP connection.

My question is how can the attacker who owns the WiFi-hotspot steal my password by injecting the malicious JavaScript code without leaving any trace? Will URL still remain the `tmail.com` when I am accessing this or will it change? Where (application layer/network layer) and how (download the web page or modify network layer data) exactly the attacker will make the changes to succeed?

I am asking this question purely for educational purpose. I am just curious and have no intent to harm anyone.

Comment: I'm not sure enough, but you can a try a "Man In The Browser Attack" by altering java-script files to inject js payload. Check out this presentation from DEFCON  : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QT4YJn7oVI

Comment: And generally whenever you're using free wifi, make sure that you first VPN into a trusted network before logging into anything. VPN is essentially the only thing that can block MITM when accessing naked http content.

Comment: As far as I know when you are under MitM attack and your are using `https` I think the browser URL will became red instead of (usually) green. Because the certificate.

Comment: Even if you were on a secure hotspot, if you are visiting a page with an insecure connection (Http) anybody thats sniffing can read what you are sending to the router, without having to do any manipulation, as its sent in plaintext.

Comment: Just a few days ago I came across this great blog post that should answer a lot of your questions and shows how it could be done, I recommend you read it: http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/05/your-login-form-posts-to-https-but-you.html

Comment: can malicious ISP, send client its own login page without forwarding the request to tmail.com? If ISP can flip a bit, I assume it can flip all the bits and therefore send client a login page of its own, asking for the credentials of tmail.com? Is it necessary for malicious ISP to forward request for login page to tmail.com? Assuming everything is done over HTTP. Also, can any eaves dropper do this modification, or does it have to be malicious ISP (router or hotspot)?  Can a malware on the client's machine inject a java-script in the login page, before browsers display the login page?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The ISP (here, the WiFi hotspot) is what delivers pages to you. It's of course trivial for an ISP to read unsecured traffic:

[image: diagram showing that the ISP reads unsecured credentials over the wire]

Let's now consider a case where the credential submission is secured with HTTPS (so the ISP cannot sniff them right off the wire), but the HTTPS log-in page loads an unsecured script, `helper.js`. The ISP can inject any behavior into that non-HTTPS script before it finally serves the script to the browser. For example, the ISP can inject the instructions, "*When this page submits credentials, send a copy of them to `evil.example.com`.*" The diagram below shows secured requests and responses in green and insecure requests/responses in other colors:

[image: diagram showing that the ISP modifies the page content to contain a malicious script]

When your browser requests `helper.js` over HTTP, the malicious ISP responds with a resource that has the wrong content. Your browser has no idea what `helper.js` should look like, and without any integrity validation measure (like HTTPS), the browser has no idea anything is wrong. Your browser assumes it has correctly been served `http://tmail.com/helper.js`, because that's what it asked for and the ISP sent back a response without any complaint (e.g., the response was an HTTP `200` for `/helper.js`). The fact that *what your browser got* is different from *what the real server sent* is totally irrelevant, because your browser has no way to detect that this difference occurred.

Based on your comments, you seem to think that modifying a resource can only be done by redirecting the browser to another resource. This is incorrect. Consider **Bob** the browser, **Iggy** the ISP, and two servers, **Alice** and **Mallory**.

First, consider the honest case:

- Bob wants to know Alice's favorite food.

  - Bob says to Iggy, "Hey, Iggy, please send a `GET /favoritefood` to `alice.com`."
  - Iggy asks Alice about her favorite food. Alice tells him, "Pizza, but with no onions, because I hate onions."
  - Iggy comes back to Bob and says "Hey, I have that response for your `GET /favoritefood` from `alice.com`! She says she loves pizza, but not onions."

Now let's consider a dishonest case:

- Bob wants to know Alice's favorite food.

  - Bob says to Iggy, "Hey, Iggy, please send a `GET /favoritefood` to `alice.com`."
  - Iggy comes back to Bob and says, "`301 Moved Permanently` -- ask Mallory about Alice's favorite food instead"
  - Bob then sends Iggy to `GET /favoritefood` from `mallory.com` instead. It's a different resource, and Bob *knows* it's a different resource from the one he originally asked for.

In this case, the browser's address bar would be different from what you originally typed in: `mallory.com/favoritefood` instead of `alice.com/favoritefood`.

Now consider this case instead:

- Bob wants to know Alice's favorite food.

  - Bob says to Iggy, "Hey, Iggy, please send a `GET /favoritefood` to `alice.com`."
  - Iggy asks Alice about her favorite food. Alice tells him, "Pizza, but with no onions, because I hate onions."
  - Iggy comes back to Bob and says "Hey, I have that response for your `GET /favoritefood` from `alice.com`! She says she loves to eat lots and lots of onions."

There's no other resources involved. `http://alice.com/favoritefood` is the only resource being fetched here; Iggy simply lied about what the contents of the resource were. There is no way for Bob to detect that Iggy is lying, because there is no integrity-validating system in place.

**One final attempt at explanation:** suppose the ISP is honest but mistakenly flipped a single bit when delivering the contents of the HTML file. Surely you would not expect such a mistake to cause the web page to load under a different domain. Now suppose that the honest ISP mistakenly flipped two bits instead of just one: again, such a mistake would never cause the domain or resource path to change. Now suppose the ISP flipped two thousand bits by honest mistake (perhaps the ISP has a faulty switch some place, or the WiFi router was hit by cosmic rays): again, no need for the domain to change. Now suppose the change was done maliciously instead of by mistake: again, the change in intent causes no change in what is actually happening. The resource path and origin, as identified in the browser's address bar, remains unchanged, while the ISP is free to change the contents of the resource (honestly or dishonestly) without detection.

Comment: I understood the case when .js file is seprate from html file. Can the wifi-hotspot attacker modify the java script snippet embedded in the html code ?

Comment: If the HTML page is protected by HTTPS, no. If the HTML page is not protected by HTTPS, yes. If the HTML page is not protected by HTTPS, the ISP can directly change *anything* about the page and can sniff credentials directly off the wire as in my first diagram. (If the log-in page is unsecured, but sends the credentials through a secure unsniffable channel, it's trivial to change the behavior of the unsecured page to use an insecure channel instead.)

Comment: i understood the case when the client makes the second request (.js file) and gets a malicious code from the wifi-hotspot. Because the html file is already received and browser request for .js file to which the attacker can respond with malicious evil.js script. But I didn't get how can the code be modified in the first request(.html). In which layer this is done, application?

Comment: @Curious "Because the html file is already received.." -- we perform the modification on the HTML resource *before* the HTML resource is received. The ISP can modify ***any*** non-HTTPS traffic: HTML, JS, CSS, office documents, binary executable, etc., etc. There's no difference between modifying a JS file and modifying an HTML file. I don't entirely understand why you're treating the cases of a JS file and an HTML file differently. They're all insecure resources being processed by the ISP.

Comment: @Curious I've edited my based on your comments. I think you believe that a *modification* requires some kind of *HTTP redirect*. This is not correct.

Comment: yes, i think that web page is downloaded, then changes are made by wifi-hotsppt malicious machine. But now the machine becomes the originator of the web page and i think the url on the requested client should reflect the malicious machine as host and not the tmail.com. I think i am wrong.

Comment: so the ip address basically remains that of tmail.com, even though the data is modified by the malicious wifi-hotspot. So the changes are made at network layer or the application layer. I am confused as to why the ip address of malicious host is not reflected on the requesting client machine.

Comment: @Curious, when the malicious wifi-hotspot delivers the html page of tmail.com, it simply modifies the last few bytes to insert something like: script src="http : //evil.com/badscript.js".  Your browser still displays tmail.com, but the page is not what they sent you - it's been altered by the MITM. They are delivering packets, and can easily change the contents of the packets without changing the source and destination addresses of the packets.

Comment: @Curious I've edited to add one final attempt at explanation, where we consider a single flipped bit, changed by honest mistake by the ISP.

Comment: can malicious ISP, send client its own login page without forwarding the request to tmail.com? If ISP can flip a bit, I assume it can flip all the bits and therefore send client a login page of its own, asking for the credentials of tmail.com? Is it necessary for malicious ISP to forward request for login page to tmail.com? Assuming everything is done over HTTP.

Comment: Also, can any eaves dropper do this modification, or does it have to be malicious ISP (router or hotspot)? Traffic is over HTTP. Can a malware on the client's machine inject a java-script in the login page, before browsers display the login page?

Comment: Did I just describe the phishing attack in the second last comment? :)

Comment: @Curious yes the attacker can send anything it wants as an answer to a request, but usually the attacker doesn't want to be detected, the user may get suspicious, if he enters his credentials in the fake-login page and is not logged in to his mail-provider afterwards. - So the 'silent' approach is to let him log in and just grab the credentials without him knowing!

Comment: @Curious -yes a local malware can do what it wants, it can flip any bit on your screen and show you whatever it wants - even HTTPS cannot help you with a local malware infection. To do modifications you have to overwrite the original traffic - so you have to get into the paket-delivery-lane for the client, so a Router,ISP,DNS or other ways. But this could also be done by ARP spoofing from someone with a laptop in the same public wifi as you

Answer (score 3):

I assume the login form on tmail.com will be send with https. Otherwise you can read the plain password with a packet inspector.

Your browser loads a webpage from tmail.com. The wifi owner can add a JavaScript into this page. This script will log whatever you type into the login form of the mail provider and store it somewhere.

> Will URL still remain the tmail.com when I am accessing this or will it change?

yes, it will all look the same. But the page source code contains addional JavaScript.

> Where (application layer/network layer) and how (download the web page or modify network layer data) exactly the attacker will make the changes to succeed?

In the application layer he will change the webpage.

**Update**

For better understanding you might like to get [mitmproxy.org](http://mitmproxy.org/) and use the [replacement](http://mitmproxy.org/doc/features/replacements.html) tool:

```
:~q:</html>:<script>alert('hi')</script></html>
```

This will add a JavaScript to all html pages passing through.

Comment: If the changes to the webpage are done in the application layer, then the attacker has to download and make the changes. How exactly this is done? If the attacker downloads and make changes, it will be stored on the local machine, how can the actual web page be changed on fly and forwarded to my machine?

Comment: @Curious it is called "transparent proxy". the idea is, that all traffic to port 80 (or any other port) is filtered thru the program. usual proxy would just cache the result, so that further requests are served faster, but malicious owner of proxy can set it up to modify the pages

Comment: If you connected to a wifi everything you download is "downloaded" by the wifi router and forwarded to you. The WiFi access point can modify this data on the fly as it pass through.

Comment: How exactly this data is modified? Can you elaborate further?

Comment: @Curious Not sure what you like to know here. You read until you hit a </html> tag and insert you <script> infront of it.

Comment: @PiTheNumber, modifying the code is fine, how can I fake the source of the file, If the machine hosting wifi-hotspot make the changes, the url will be that of the machine and not of the tmail.com, isn't it? I want to know how the url tmail.com remains intact when the source code is modified by the wifi-hotspot. I imagine, the wifi-hotspot downloads the code, modifies it and sends it to the requesting machine. But now the machine hosting the wifi-hotpsot(evilhotspot.com) becomes the originator of the web page and url(evilhotspot.com) should reflect that, am I thinking wrong?

Comment: @Curious First have a look how [http works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Server_response). I linked to the server response. This is what the server tmail.com sends back to you. Here the script is injected. Now you need to know how [TCP/IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite) works. The data (server response) is send as a TCP/IP packet from the server to you passing several router. Run `traceroute tmail.com` to see them. Every router can modify the data in the packet. See [Man-in-the-middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

Comment: so basically injection is done at network layer?

Comment: @Curious Injection is done at the network layer, with possibly some changes to the application layer (e.g., modifying the `Content-Length` header to reflect the length of the modified document).

Comment: @Curious: Don't confuse equipment with layer. The injection must be done by network equipment (routers, switch) but routers and switches can implement application layer code as well (after all, most routers are just linux boxes). HTTP proxying is application layer logic.

Comment: Can I do this changes on my windows 7 machine? When and where I have to make this changes to inject a malicious java-script?

Comment: Download a copy of [MITM Proxy](http://mitmproxy.org/) and have a play around. Modifying traffic is done on-the-fly.